# Json.net escaping or removing a character on SerializeObject

Tags: json.net

I am using Mvc 4 with Json.Net. I have an error message property with the follong content on the server:

```
"'Instalation Name' should not be empty."
```

On the client I am doing something like this:

```
'@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()))';
```

and the output is the following:

```
"ErrorMessage":"'Instalation Name' should not be empty."
```

which is throwing error:

```
Expected ';'
```

I need a way to escape or remove the `'` character. How can I do this? One way is to do custom JsonConverter ... Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to post the code for the object you are trying to serialize?

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `@Html.Raw()` is placed within `<script></script>`. So I suggest you just remove the `'` characters around your JSON, so it looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var v = @Html.Raw(...);

</script>
```

So the the variable `v` will receive the deserialized data directly.